# C# selenium cant load profile

Tags: c#, selenium

i have a problem using a profile i created for my chromedriver. Each time i try to use the profile, it seem working but when chrome start, it ask me to set the profile. I already created the profile from my normal chrome browser with an gmail account but it seem selenium chrome browser ask me to chose and setup my profile.

Here is what it shown:

[image]

When i use this profile with normal chrome browser this is what Profile 2 look like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();


    var c = new ChromeOptions();
    c.AddArguments(@"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
    c.AddArguments(@"--profile-directory=C:\Users\user\Desktop\Profile 2");
    //c.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.cookie_controls_mode", 0);
    c.AddExcludedArgument("--enable-automation");
    c.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
    c.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    c.AddArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors");
    c.AddArgument("start-maximized");
    c.AddArguments("--lang=en");
    c.AddArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    c.AddArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.87 Mobile Safari/537.36");

    //var commandTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

    d = new ChromeDriver(/*service, */c/*, commandTimeout*/);

    //ChromeDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
    //var wait = new WebDriverWait(d, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
    d.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

So basically it feel like selenium load the profile but it seem that i need to seting the profile again and again. How can i use the profile that i made??? I would like to being able to use profile cookies and etc.

I followed almost every tutorial from here, there is some good post about it but nothing about the profile setup page when you try to load a profile to selenium. I really need help it would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppeteer on headless do the samething so i guess its a common issue with headless browser.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32131378)

Comment: Nobodies responded, so i tried to gave the most usefull answer so it can help ppl... instead, you should appreciate my effort...